# Flutter project when run showing Error Invalid argument(s): The source must not be null

Tags: android, mobile, flutter

I'm new to flutter. I created a simple flutter project when I trying to run. I was getting this error `Unexpected failure from adb: Invalid argument(s): The source must not be null`

`Error launching the application on emulator-5554`
This is my simple flutter application code:

```
import `package:flutter/material.dart`;
 void main(){
    runApp(
       new Center(
        child: new Text(
          "hello, world",
           textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
        )
       )
    );
 }
```

Can anyone suggest me what might be the issue? How should I have to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the issue just because of ADB, Means your device or emulator not connected properly may be losing cable or anything else so please be verify first your device connected perfectly this issue regarding adb or device connection.

Comment: thanks. Now I'm getting this error `Error connecting to the service protocol: Exception: No Flutter view is available`

Comment: just now I refresh and I got the output.

Comment: I am having this same issue but i dont think the issue is related to ADB since I am able to debug the application using the native code via android studio. I am also able to view the devices using `$ adb devices -l
List of devices attached
ad08160338d72d5361     device product:heroltexx model:SM_G930F device:herolte transport_id:1`

Comment: @Husna, can you tell me what you did to resolve this issue?

Comment: @ScrappyI just restart the project and got the output.

Answer (score 3):

When you connect the phone, there is options like USB Tethering, MIDI, PTP, file transfer etc...
Choose PTP. 
If it doesn't work try MIDI.
It will work.